# Umbraco Slow On Azure

Tags: azure, umbraco

We are currently hosting an Umbraco site on Azure and it is oddly very slow. When hosting locally it seems to run fine. I've checked that the umbraco.config file and internal index are being created and they are, so I'm guessing it is using the Umbraco XML cache to query content. Is there anything else I should be looking for?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Azure SQL Database or SQL Server on a Virtual Machine? Check to make sure you're running your web server in the same region as the database you're using. Then check to make sure the instances for both the database and the web server are correctly sized based on workload.

Comment: It's an Azure SQL Database, I believe it is in the same region, but I will double check. The workload isn't that large, there isn't that much content in the site and it is currently in beta so it is not getting much traffic. I believe right now the web server has 2 cores and 8 gigs of ram. What are minimum requirements for Umbraco?

Comment: Right now, both the website and database are in the same region

Comment: Umbraco don't provide hard and fast guides on CPU/RAM. Best you can do is to review the usage of the host via the Azure portal and see how it is behaving. What size database are you using? Have you checked to see if you have any of the debug flags on that might be pumping out logs to disk which would slow things down.

Comment: I've set all necessary configuration to make sure debug logging is off and it still doesn't seem to help. The max size of the database is set to 1 GB and we are currently at 300MB

Comment: What Azure SQL Database tier are you using?

Comment: Right now it is the standard tier

Comment: Doesn't make sense right? Like I said it runs fine locally. We can't seem to track down what exactly is slowing this azure website instance... Are there any guidelines for deploying Umbraco to Azure?

Comment: If this is hosted on an Azure Websites instance ensure you're running on the minimum of a Standard level instance to ensure you're running on dedicated compute.